# C# Open one form from another?

Tags: c#

I was wondering how you would go about opening a form that you have already made from the first form. For example, in a .vb project, I can create two forms, and simply do form2.Show(), and it will show the form with everything I've added to it, etc.. In c#, how would you do this? I've done this so far, because I haven't found another way:

```
private void menuBar_CheckForUpdates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form updateForm = new Form();
    updateForm.Show();
}
```

However, I want to be able to open the form I created manually, and added controls to. How would I do this? I would rather not place all the controls on the new form in code.

Comment: I would suggest doing a google search on the following `C# adding Controls Dynamically at RunTime` also if you are not familiar with C# there are some really good tutorials online that you can quickly get yourself up to speed.. understand the basics before you can move on to the more advanced..

Comment: `Form2 updateForm = new Form2();` - `updateForm.Show();`.

Comment: Your code already seems to be correct - although from the answers and comments so far your question is being interpreted in a number of different ways. Can you make it less ambiguous? eg are you talking about adding controls at runtime?

Comment: Sorry about that. What I mean is, let's say I create a new form in the solution explorer (not while the program is running) and I call it updateForm.cs Now let's say I drag on a text box, and a label, etc.. So It's not a blank form anymore. Well in a .vb form, I could just do updateForm.Show() and it would show the form a created, with all the controls I dropped onto it. Well I want to do the same with the .cs form. But the only thing i've been able to do right now is create a new form, create a new text box, and assign it each time. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @DonaldCox : You get a new form because you keep declaring an empty form. Do this instead: `updateForm updateFrm = new updateForm();    updateFrm.Show();`.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue.

Comment: The VB.NET equivalent for example, would be `Dim updateFrm As New updateForm`.

Comment: Yet another case of a VB 'feature' (default form instances) hampering programmer development.  But it does save 1 line of code !

Answer (score 2):

Every form you create in the designer is a normal class (with a designer-generated method that creates the controls).

You can create an instance of that class and `Show()` it.

Comment: How would I create an instance of the other form?

Comment: With the `new` operator, just like any other class.